# What is the purpose of std::ostream& out for this friend overloaded operator function and not just std::cout?

Tags: c++, syntax, ostream

Can someone explain the purpose of `std::ostream &out` for this friend overloaded operator function? Why not just use `std::cout` inside the function?

```cpp
friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Complex& c) 
{
    out << c.real;
    out << "+i" << c.imag << endl;

    return out;
}
```

Instead, like so:

```cpp
friend operator<<(const Complex& c) 
{ 
    std::cout << c.real;
    std::cout << "+i" << c.imag << endl;
}
```

Comment: Do you understand the basics of operator overloading and friend functions? How much needs to be explained here?

Comment: As you tagged [tag:syntax], that is well explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/what-are-the-basic-rules-and-idioms-for-operator-overloading).

Comment: `operator<<` needs two arguments. It seems you are trying to write an overload for some form of unary shift operator, which does not exist.

Answer (score 9):

Because this way you can use any `ostream` as output, not just `std::cout`
for example, `std::clog << c;`

Comment: Yes! `std::ostringstream` would be another very useful stream.

Answer (score 4):

Displaying the output in a function and returning the output stream to the overloaded friend function have different meanings.

You can pass the initialized `std::ostream&` to any other `ostream&`. For example, `std::cout`, `std::clog`, `std::cerr`.

Note that this can be passed to the file stream instances such as `std::ofstream` when writing to a file.<sup>**1**</sup>

Also, in your second given example:

```
friend operator<<(const Complex &c)
```

You are missing a return type. The program will fail to compile. Also, two arguments are required to overload the `operator<<`.

---

<sup>1. Thanks to [@Pete Becker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66338832/what-is-the-purpose-of-stdostream-out-for-this-friend-overloaded-operator-fun/66338901#comment117283780_66338901) for suggesting this important information.</sup>

Comment: Don't forget file streams.

Comment: Yes, that's better. The key is that **any** kind of output stream can be passed to a stream inserter. The inserter doesn't care where the output is going; it just looks at the values of the object and puts appropriate text into the stream. That way you don't have to write different functions for different output media. None of that `printf`, `sprintf`, `fprintf` malarkey. +1.

Answer (score 2):

This:

> ```
> friend std::ostream & operator << (std::ostream &out, const Complex &c) 
> { 
>     out << c.real; 
>     out << "+i" << c.imag << endl; 
>     return out; 
> }
> ```

is the function that gets called when you write:

```
Complex c;
std::cout << c;    // same as: operator<<( std::cout, c);
```

Calling `std::cout << c;` inside the implementation of `operator<<` would be bad, because then it would call itself recursively with no end.